# macOS Terminal.app can't split with Command + D

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm, zsh

I installed zsh. When I press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in iTerm2, it could split normally.

But when I return to using Terminal.app, I use bash or zsh, it `can't split` with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, it changed like the screenshot below.

#### Before pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

#### After pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well dang. This appears to be a bug of some sort - pressing cmd+D in Terminal window causes window background to become clear. Doesn't revert to a visible background until window is resized. That is weird as heck. Same behavior when using menu option instead of shortcut keys. Have you tried reporting the bug to Apple?

Answer (score 1):

I've reported this as an issue on Apple Communities and also reported it as a bug to Apple Support. Until it is fixed, there seems to be no workaround.

Comment: I have the same problem.
Could you give a link to this issue? A link to the reported bug? Thank you

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250330021 is the Communities post. Bug was submitted through the Support link listed there.